# How to specify schemalocation for an xsd in local folder, while importing it into a wsdl file

Tags: namespaces, xsd, wsdl

I have a XSD in local , and I need to import the same into a WSDL. I have couple of other xsds too which are already on the production namespace.

Now I have little clue as how to make this XSD that is only in my local to be made available in my WSDL file to test the webservice using soapUI.

So questions, what will be the namespace and how will i provide the schemalocation.

(I am a newbie to wsdl Namspaces, so plz dont mind this basic question. Googling simply does not tell me anything about the how to.)

For the ones that are in Prod its like this:
[image]

Comment: I found a way, added the schema file to the same folder as of the wsdl file, and stripped of the uri part of the schemaLocation value. It imported well into the soapUI.

Comment: But still got the other question, how to host the schema files on my localhost.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way, added the schema file to the same folder as of the wsdl file, and stripped of the uri part of the schemaLocation value. It imported well into the soapUI.
But still got the other question, how to host the schema files on my localhost.